# PHP POST is creating empty row

Tags: php, post

I have located the error into these lines, but I don't know where it is exactly. Can you please help me?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO log (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Action)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $_POST['Year'], $_POST['Month'], $_POST['Day'], 
        $_POST['Hour'], $_POST['Minute'], $_POST['Action']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: have you checked what you have in `$_POST`? (`var_dump($_POST)`)

Comment: And you probably don't want to execute that code if the fields are empty.

Comment: is there a specific reason for storing a datetime spread onto 5 fields?

Comment: If those values aren't present in $_POST, are they supposed to be coming from a form? If so, check that all your inputs have names and that the form method is set to post. Also keep in mind that the array keys are case sensitive.

Comment: Where's your form?

Comment: I have considered the keysensitive part. Datetime is onto 5 fields by requerimients of boss. My major concern is about if this code is correct. What I can read is that the problem maybe comes from the sent data, right?

Comment: Most likely. You should dump $_POST as previously suggested or step through with a debugger to be sure. If there was a problem with that code, it's unlikely that a blank record would be inserted. More likely the query would not be able to execute.

Comment: okey, I´ll check that, thanks all of you